# How to configure a OneDrive folder as online-only by default

Tags: microsoft-office-365

I'm using some OneDrive space as a target for backups.  I don't want these large files replicated to all my computers connected to the OneDrive account.  I know I can configure selective sync for the backup folder on a computer by computer basis, but is there a way to mark the folder as online-only?

The goal would be that if I connect another computer to the account in the future, I wouldn't have to remember to configure selective sync on it to prevent the backup folder from being copied locally.

Comment: Not to be confused, you're asking about "OneDrive"? the app that comes with Windows? or "OneDrive for Business"? the app that is being used with Office 365? because both have different functionality and settings.

Comment: I think your wording may not be exactly correct.  I am talking about OneDrive for Office 365, but not OneDrive for Business.  IOW, I have a family subscription (not business) to Office 365.  For Windows 8.1, I don't see the selective sync UI, so I can't pick and choose what gets replicated and what doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

There are no online settings available to restrict a folder from Sharing.  The only method currently is to do this when you configure the other machines for initial syncing, you will need to exclude that folder at that time, or update settings if you are already configured for syncing.